# PHP laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, modal-dialog

So I'm a coding bootcamp student and just posted a question but realized I gave the snippet of the wrong code and decided to delete that and repost it here.
I'm making a crossfit web application and am having trouble with looping through creating modals that relate the users/profiles together.
here is my resource SearchController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //
    //dump($request->user());die();
      return view('user.search')
          ->withUsers(User::all())
          ->withProfile(Profile::where('user_id', $request->user()->id));
}
```

and here is my blade.php file:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <li class = "list-group-item">
      {{$user->id}}:
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$user->id}}">
          {{$user->name}}
      </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$user->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                  <p>{{$profile->name}}</p>
                  <img src = "{{$profile->img_link}}" alt = "profile_pic" height="200" width="200">
                  <li><p><strong>Location: </strong>{{$profile->location}}</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Age: </strong>{{$profile->age}}</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Height: </strong>{{$profile->height}}</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Affiliate: </strong>{{$profile->affiliate}}</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Front Squat: </strong>{{$profile->front_squat}} lbs</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Back Squat: </strong>{{$profile->back_squat}} lbs</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Clean and Jerk: </strong>{{$profile->clean_and_jerk}} lbs</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Snatch: </strong>{{$profile->snatch}} lbs</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Deadlift: </strong>{{$profile->deadlift}} lbs</p></li>
                  <li><p><strong>Bio: </strong>{{$profile->bio}}</p></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="/message">Message</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

So when you click on a modal button it only brings up the information from the very last profile that has been entered into my mysql database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your modal is using `$profile` and not `$user` which is always linked to the current user?

Comment: Don't delete your old posts and repost them again.

Comment: Mangus I posted the ProfileController portion and not the SearchController and meant to hit edit but hit delete

Comment: Sorry I am brand new to asking for help/coding, I do not mean to make anybody mad

Comment: No worries. I'm not mad. it's just important that people stick to their original posts. If not, it's kind of rude to all the people that tried to help on the old one + new visitors won't have the comment/answer history. After a question is posted on SO, it, and all answers belongs to the community.

Comment: Never thought about it that way and yea, totally get it now.

Comment: Yes Peter i'm passing the value to find profile where user->id is

Comment: I have a couple of questions, are you trying to fetch the profile associated to the currently logged in user? If so does your user.php model have a profile method that says it hasOne App\Profile? If that's the case let me know and I can suggest an easy fix for you.

Comment: public function profile() {
      //Profile Model belongs to User Model
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    } .

Comment: So yes I'm trying to fetch the profile associated with the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

If as you are just trying to fetch the profiles of all users, you can do it like this:

SearchController.php:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
      return view('user.search')
          ->withUsers(User::all());
}
```

And in your blade.php file you can just do this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
          <li class = "list-group-item">
              {{$user->id}}:
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$user->id}}">
                  {{$user->name}}
              </button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$user->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul>
                          <p>{{$user->profile->name}}</p>
                          <img src = "{{$user->profile->img_link}}" alt = "profile_pic" height="200" width="200">
                          <li><p><strong>Location: </strong>{{$user->profile->location}}</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Age: </strong>{{$user->profile->age}}</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Height: </strong>{{$user->profile->height}}</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Affiliate: </strong>{{$user->profile->affiliate}}</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Front Squat: </strong>{{$user->profile->front_squat}} lbs</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Back Squat: </strong>{{$user->profile->back_squat}} lbs</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Clean and Jerk: </strong>{{$user->profile->clean_and_jerk}} lbs</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Snatch: </strong>{{$user->profile->snatch}} lbs</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Deadlift: </strong>{{$user->profile->deadlift}} lbs</p></li>
                          <li><p><strong>Bio: </strong>{{$user->profile->bio}}</p></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="/message">Message</a></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </li>
        @endforeach
```

Right now you will be displaying all users, and for each of those users you will be displaying their profiles as well, just make sure you have this in your user.php file:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for, If it's not then tell me what's missing and I'll do my best to help, cheers!